# No post content on review result page for Low Quality Posts queue if review resolution set to close

Tags: bug, review, low-quality-posts

On the [history tab of Low Quality Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/history) there is a column with review resolution:

> [image: LQP table]

When you click on a link with "Close" resolution there is no post content on the result page, [e.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/74934):

> [image: No post for close]

Any other resolution, i.e. Looks OK, Recommend Deletion, Delete refers to the page where post content is present, [e.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/74859):

> [image: Deleted post]